# Woocommerce - Filtering products based on attribute

Tags: wordpress, customization, woocommerce

I was hoping someone could help me, I'm trying to create a filtering menu for product attributes. I have the attributes being listed out just fine but when you click on them they take you to the 'Archive' page which lists the correct products. Now is there anyway I can make it so when the user click on an attribute it shows the filtered products but using the 'shop' template/page. So not linking to the archive page??

Any ideas?

I have looked into the Layered Nav widget, its closed to what I'm wanting but I don't like how you can select multiple attributes. I just want it to do i one by one.

thanks guys/gals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page has an answer: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-custom-attributes-in-menus/
At the bottom you'll see how to create a proper template for selected attributes pages.

Notice that your taxonomy-product_cat.php copy should be put into your theme folder, not to woocommerce folder in your theme.

It works for me.